# Retrieve data from database according to multiple checked items from CheckedListBox

Tags: vb.net

**How to retrieve data from database according to multiple checked items from CheckedListBox?       PlEASE GUIDE ME!!!**

I'm currently doing a tutorial regarding to retrieve data from table according to multiple checked items from a CheckedListBox. Right now i'm able to retrieve data from table by only 1 checked item. how to make it retrievable by multiples checked item?

1. checklistbox1
2. checklistbox2

The tutorial will be: first load all related data into checklistbox1 as item, and user(s) may go and check the listed item, once the user checked particulars item(s) checklistbox2 will now query out data from another table where [field] = checked item(s) from checklistbox1.

***load event as class***

```
Public Sub Startload()
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & aaa & "';Persist Security Info=False;")
        Dim dt1 As New DataTable
        Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl"
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, connection)
        Dim adpt As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)

        adpt.SelectCommand = command
        adpt.Fill(dt1)
        CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "name"
        CheckedListBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
        CheckedListBox1.DataSource = dt1
    End Sub
```

***when Checked change execute checkedload()***

```
 Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
        Label1.Text = CheckedListBox1.SelectedValue
        checkedload()
    End Sub
```

***After checked items from checklistbox1 (checkedload) will execute and retrieves data and show in checklistbox2***

```
Private Sub checkedload()
        Dim x As String = Label1.Text
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & aaa & "';Persist Security Info=False;")
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        Dim sqlstr2 As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE [name]='" & x & "'"
        Dim command2 As New OleDbCommand(sqlstr2, connection)
        Dim adpt2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(command2)

        adpt2.SelectCommand = command2
        adpt2.Fill(dt2)
        CheckedListBox2.DisplayMember = "namex"
        CheckedListBox2.ValueMember = "ID"
        CheckedListBox2.DataSource = dt2
    End Sub
```

Comment: does it fetch values from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Self Solved**

```
Dim i As Integer
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & aaa & "';Persist Security Info=False;")
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step i + 1
            If CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
                Dim xx As String = (CType(CheckedListBox1.Items(i), DataRowView))("name")
                Dim sqlstr2 As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE [name]='" & xx & "'"
                Dim command2 As New OleDbCommand(sqlstr2, connection)
                Dim adpt2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(command2)
                adpt2.SelectCommand = command2
                adpt2.Fill(dt2)
                CheckedListBox2.DisplayMember = "namex"
                CheckedListBox2.ValueMember = "ID"
                CheckedListBox2.DataSource = dt2
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
 Dim i as Integer=0
 For Each li as ListItem in CheckedListBox1.Items
      If li.Selected=True Then
         Dim lab As New Label
         lab.ID="lab" & i
         lab.Text=li.SelectedItem.Value
         i += 1
      End If
 Next
 hiddenfield1.Value=i    'hidden field 
 checkedload()
End Sub

Private Sub checkedload()
  For i as Integer = o To hiddenField1.Value 
    Dim x As String = Request.Form("lab" & i)
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & aaa & "';Persist Security Info=False;")
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    Dim sqlstr2 As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE [name]='" & x & "'"
    Dim command2 As New OleDbCommand(sqlstr2, connection)
    Dim adpt2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(command2)

    adpt2.SelectCommand = command2
    adpt2.Fill(dt2)
    CheckedListBox2.DisplayMember = "namex"
    CheckedListBox2.ValueMember = "ID"
    CheckedListBox2.DataSource = dt2
  Next
End Sub
```

I haven't checked it anyway. but it could help you

Comment: erm thx for the guide but not understand with it (hiddenField1.value)?

Comment: hidden field is for the number of items u have checked

Comment: `For Each li as ListItem in CheckedListBox1.Items
      If li.Selected=True Then
         Dim lab As New Label
         lab.ID="lab" & i
         lab.Text=li.SelectedItem.Value
         i += 1
      End If
 Next`    ' "ListItem" and "lab.ID="lab" & i" occurred error!!!